# How do I determine the direction vector for this vector equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

The vector equation we have is:

$[x, y] = [-1, 2] + t[1, -1]$

I'm a little lost here in determining how to figure out the direction vector. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Is t a parameter, like time?

Comment: Yes t is a parameter/ @Jedediyah

Comment: Ok, so the vector is just [-1+t, 2-t] since you take the first part and add (component-wise) t times the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be $ \vec{v} = (1,-1)$ treated as a vector and not a point. To see this is the case, you take $2$ points $A = (-1,2), B = (0,1)$, then $v = \vec{AB} = (0-(-1),1-2) = (1,-1)$ as claimed.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, could you provide an explanation of how you arrived at this?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: This answers a slightly different question.  The $[-1,2]$ and $[1,-1]$ given in the problem are vectors, not points.  Also, the parameter $t$ means there is not a non-parameterized in this case.  The direction is dependent on $t$ since $[-1,2]$ does not happen to be in the same direction as $[1,-1]$.

Answer (score 2):

So you can think of the $t$ being distributed to the second vector.  Treat it like a scalar.  Vector addition is done (in this component form) one component at a time (combine the $x$s and then the $y$s).  So you have
$$
[x,y] = [-1,2] +t [1,-1] 
$$
$$
= [-1,2]+[t,-t] 
$$
$$
= [-1+t,2-t]
$$
using your notation.